# VBA run code in another instance of excel and detach

Tags: vba, excel, instance

I currently have the below code which opens a workbook in a new instance of excel (The workbook that is opened has an on open macro).

However when the code is running in the new instance, this also takes up the existing instance of excel and only frees it once the workbook open macro has run.Is there a way to open excel in a new instance and detach/stop the code from the existing workbook immediately?

Please see code below.

```
Sub OpenWBInNewInstance()
    Dim xApp As Excel.Application
    Set xApp = New Excel.Application
    xApp.Visible = True

    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Set wb = xApp.Workbooks.Open("Z:\MI\Not Purchased Detail\Not Purchased Detail Disposal Marketing Template.xlsb")
End Sub
```

Comment: Nope. VBA can't run on multiple threads so execution will only be returned to this code once it has finished the entire "open" event. Only way I know of to get around this is to output the command to a VBS file and shell that instead

Comment: Do you *want* the open event to run? If not, just disable events before you open the workbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code execution runs on a single thread in VBA, so you can't do what you're asking because the execution won't move to the next line until the entire `Workbooks.Open` line has been processed - which includes the `Workbook_Open` event in the other workbook.

A possible workaround it to use VBScript instead:

```
    Sub OpenWBInNewInstance()

    Open Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\temp.vbs" For Output As #1
        Print #1, "Set xl = CreateObject(""Excel.Application"")"
        Print #1, "xl.Workbooks.Open ""Z:\MI\Not Purchased Detail\Not Purchased Detail Disposal Marketing Template.xlsb"""
    Close #1

    Shell Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\temp.vbs"

    '// You will need some kind of hook here to set the workbook in other instance...
```